# Can't run .class files from CMD

Tags: java, cmd

I am unable to run .class files from CMD, and I can't seem to find a way to get around the error messages. My environment variable is set to C:\program files (x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin, both java and javac are version 1.7.0_45 and I am running the code in the local directory:

```
C:\Java\hfjavafinalsamples\chap01> javac PhraseOMatic.java

C:\Java\hfjavafinalsamples\chap01> java -classpath . PhraseOMatic
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PhraseOMatic (wrong n
ame: chap01/PhraseOMatic)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)


C:\Java\hfjavafinalsamples\chap01>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an chapter on "packages" in chap00 or chap01 :-)

Comment: There is, and I followed it, as well as other tutorials. It does not address this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fully qualified name of the class is `chap01.PhraseOMatic`, because its simple name is `PhraseOMatic`, and its package is `chap01`.

The java command expects a fully qualified name. Based on its classpath and on this fully qualified name, it will look for the .class file. So, if your classpath is '.' and the fully qualified name is `chap01.PhraseOMatic`, it will look for `./chap01/PhraseOMatic`. So that won't work, since you're already inside the chap01 folder package.

The classpath should thus be `..`, or (better) you should be in the hfjavafinalsamples folder to run your application:

```
C:\Java\hfjavafinalsamples> java -classpath . chap01.PhraseOMatic
```

Also, you should not put the source files (.java) and the compiled files (.class) in the same folder tree. Create an `src` folder containing the source tree, and a `classes` file containing the compiled classes tree. and use the `-d classes` option of javac to compile the classes to the classes folder.